# WildFly-maven-plugin: WFLYCTL0412: Required services that are not installed:

Tags: wildfly, maven-plugin, wildfly-maven-plugin

I am trying to configure WildFly using **wildfly-maven-plugin** and I keep getting different exceptions, but non of my approaches works.

```
    Failed to execute goal org.wildfly.plugins:wildfly-maven-plugin:2.0.1.Final:execute-commands (Configure2) on project xp-distribution: Command execution failed for command '        attribute-mapping=[{index=1, to=roles}]}])'. {
    "outcome" => "failed",
    "failure-description" => {
        "WFLYCTL0412: Required services that are not installed:" => ["org.wildfly.data-source.xpDS"],
        "WFLYCTL0180: Services with missing/unavailable dependencies" => ["org.wildfly.security.security-realm.xpDbRealm is missing [org.wildfly.data-source.xpDS]"]
    },
    "rolled-back" => true
}
```

my configuration looks like:

```
<plugin>
<groupId>org.wildfly.plugins</groupId>
<artifactId>wildfly-maven-plugin</artifactId>
<version>2.0.1.Final</version>
<executions>
    <execution>
        <id>start-wildfly1</id>
        <goals>
            <goal>start</goal>
        </goals>
        <phase>prepare-package</phase>
    </execution>
    <execution>
        <id>Configure1</id>
        <phase>install</phase>
        <goals>
            <goal>execute-commands</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
            <commands>
                <command>module add --name=org.postgresql
                    --dependencies=javax.api,javax.transaction.api
                    --resources=${project.build.directory}${file.separator}postgresql-${version.postgres.jdbc}.jar</command>
                <command>/subsystem=datasources/jdbc-driver=postgres:add(driver-name="postgres",driver-module-name="org.postgresql", driver-class-name="org.postgresql.Driver")</command>
                <command>data-source add
                    --name=xpDS
                    --driver-name=postgres
                    --connection-url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/xp_test
                    --jndi-name=java:jboss/datasources/xpDS
                    --use-java-context=true
                    --user-name=postgres
                    --password=postgres
                    --max-pool-size=25
                    --blocking-timeout-wait-millis=5000
                    --idle-timeout-minutes=5
                    --enabled=true</command>
            </commands>
        </configuration>
    </execution>
    <execution>
        <id>Configure2</id>
        <phase>install</phase>
        <goals>
            <goal>execute-commands</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
            <batch>false</batch>
            <scripts>
                <script>src/templates/xd1.cli</script>
            </scripts>
        </configuration>
    </execution>
    ...
```

I tried to restart wildfly in between adding datasource and executing script, but error stays the same. Going to target/wildfly-15.0.1.Final/modules I can see that the PostgreSQL module has been added there. Opening standalone.xml we can find that xpDS (data-source) has been added.

xd1.cli file :

```
###create JDBC-Realm for user validation
/subsystem=elytron/jdbc-realm=xpDbRealm:add( \
    principal-query=[ \
        { data-source=xpDS, \
        sql="select PASSWORD, SALT, ITERATION_COUNT from T_USER WHERE status = TRUE AND username = ?", \
        scram-mapper={algorithm=scram-sha-256,password-index=1, salt-index=2, iteration-count-index=3}}, \
        {data-source=xpDS, \
        sql="SELECT r.name AS name, 'Roles' as roles from ROLE r INNER JOIN JOIN_UO j ON j.roles = r.u_id INNER JOIN USER u ON j.users = u.um_id WHERE u.username = ?", \
        attribute-mapping=[{index=1, to=roles}]}])

###Adding user role decoders
/subsystem=elytron/simple-role-decoder=from-roles-attribute:add(attribute=roles)

:reload


###Creating a Elytron security domain and adding the created JDBC-Realms
./subsystem=elytron/security-domain=xpDbSD:add( \
    realms=[{realm=xpDbRealm, role-decoder=from-roles-attribute}, \
            {realm=local, role-mapper=super-user-mapper}], \
    default-realm=xpDbRealm, \
    permission-mapper=default-permission-mapper, post-realm-principal-transformer=myPostPrincipalTransformer)

:reload
```

Should I keep using **install phase**? Any suggestion how to fix this issue?

Comment: What version of WildFly are you using?

Comment: I am using WildFly 15.0.1.Final, with newest wildfly-maven-plugin 2.0.1.Final

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reload doesn't work so well with the plugin. However you can use offline CLI which will start an embedded server and execute the commends. You'll need to set the `jboss-home` property to use the embedded server.

Here's an example:

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>unpack</id>
            <phase>validate</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>unpack</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <artifactItems>
                    <artifactItem>
                        <groupId>org.wildfly</groupId>
                        <artifactId>wildfly-dist</artifactId>
                        <version>15.0.1.Final</version>
                        <type>zip</type>
                        <overWrite>false</overWrite>
                        <outputDirectory>target</outputDirectory>
                    </artifactItem>
                </artifactItems>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.wildfly.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>wildfly-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.1.Final</version>
    <configuration>
        <offline>true</offline>
        <jboss-home>target/wildfly-15.0.1.Final</jboss-home>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>Configure1</id>
            <phase>install</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>execute-commands</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <commands>
                    <command>embed-server</command>
                    <command>module add --name=org.postgresql
                        --dependencies=javax.api,javax.transaction.api
                        --resources=${project.build.directory}${file.separator}postgresql-${version.postgres.jdbc}.jar</command>
                    <command>/subsystem=datasources/jdbc-driver=postgres:add(driver-name="postgres",driver-module-name="org.postgresql", driver-class-name="org.postgresql.Driver")</command>
                    <command>data-source add
                        --name=xpDS
                        --driver-name=postgres
                        --connection-url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/xp_test
                        --jndi-name=java:jboss/datasources/xpDS
                        --use-java-context=true
                        --user-name=postgres
                        --password=postgres
                        --max-pool-size=25
                        --blocking-timeout-wait-millis=5000
                        --idle-timeout-minutes=5
                        --enabled=true</command>
                    <command>stop-embedded-server</command>
                </commands>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
        <execution>
            <id>Configure2</id>
            <phase>install</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>execute-commands</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <batch>false</batch>
                <scripts>
                    <script>src/templates/xd1.cli</script>
                </scripts>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

You'd need to add the `embed-server` and `stop-embedded-server` in your CLI script too.

Comment: thanks! I had to add \ after every line.  First part is being executed, however, second one is failing. 
_"WFLYCTL0412: Required services that are not installed:" => ["org.wildfly.data-source.XpDS"]_  How should I add **embed-server** to my CLI file? I added in the fisr line, without : is that correct?

Comment: but XpDS is present in standalone.xml

Comment: Yes. They are high level commands so you’d enter them without the :.

Comment: Okay, but still second Config doesn't see changes from the first one. Basically XpDS is missing, but once I open standalone manually, data source is defined there. Any idea?

Comment: Is there a reason not to just add it all to the script instead of having part of it in a script and part of it in the POM? Also make sure the server is started after these commands are executed.

Comment: The only thing that stops me from placing everything in one file is actually adding Postgres driver, the version is taken from Maven properties and with an update on I do not want to update CLI file.

Comment: Creating a single file, starting a server and running the file I get en exception: **WFLYEMB0024: The embedded server is reloading and invocations on the ModelControllerClient are not yet available**

Comment: It's ideal, especially from the plugin, to use offline CLI to configure the server. Reloads just don't work well from the plugin.

Comment: I am not sure if that didn't work with a previous WildFly or with older plugin or I did something wrong but it works perfectly fine with WildFly 19 !

I added **embed-server** and **stop-embedded-server** in every file and removed all **:reload**

Thanks @James